# Long polling too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function poll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Tail", success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
        },
        data: { datetime: getISODateTime(new Date()) },
        dataType: "json", 
        timeout: 30000
    });
})();
```

I have the above code, i am doing long polling to an endpoint.

However, it is too fast. Isnt it supposed to do it every timeout seconds?

Comment: The `timeout` only applies if the server doesn't response or provides a partial response. What are you getting back?

Comment: I m seeing too many requests going to server.

Comment: With the code you've posted, only one request will be sent to the server. But if you are running `poll()` in some loop you are likely creating a bunch of requests before responses come back. `timeout` is used to fire the `error` function when a response is taking too long.

Comment: Ok thats. True. But almost 5 request in  a sec is going.

Comment: What's true? That `poll()` is being run in a loop, if so post the code. You should also post your desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it is too fast. Isnt it supposed to do it every timeout
>   seconds?

`timeout` property here will only *timeout* the call and then fire the error. If you find it too fast, you must be doing something else besides the code posted above.

In order to do a long-polling one way could be to use Javascript `setTimeout` when you receive a response. Also, in such cases you should have an abort figured out somewhere.

**For example** (*this will poll every 3 seconds*):

```
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>


var timer;
function poll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/", success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
            timer = setTimeout(poll, 3000);
        },
        data: { datetime: new Date()},
        dataType: "json", 
        timeout: 30000
    });
};
$("#start").on("click", function() { console.log("started.."); poll(); });
$("#stop").on("click", function() { console.log("stopped.."); clearTimeout(timer); });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rf0uaaLj/

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `timeout` setting in the ajax options like this:

```
(function poll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Tail", success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
        },
        timeout: 30000,
        data: { datetime: getISODateTime(new Date()) },
        dataType: "json"
    });
})();
```

Read all about the ajax options [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: You can use `timeout` to achieve what?